# 2 hours layover and 2 separate flights - London Luton

Tags: air-travel, connecting-flights, ltn

I have a flight to London Luton (I'll be there at 3:55), then I have a flight to Lisbon and the gate closes at 5:50.

Could anyone tell me what's the procedure? Surprisingly, I couldn't find a comprehensive answer as to where I should go first after landing in Luton at 3:55. Is the boarding procedure completely the same for the next flight, as if I was a regular passenger and needed to go through the security check again or do I just get out of the first plane and look for the gate for the flight to Lisbon? Or is there another way to make it quicker?

Note: I only have my cabin luggage. No checked-in ones.

Comment: Did you buy the airplane tickets as one trip? If yes, I believe you do not need to worry, the time should be enough and if you have any problem, the airline will be responsible to find another flight for you.Also, these question you should ask for the crew when you will be traveling.

Comment: It's not one trip - these are two separate tickets  (I already printed my boarding passes as well) - and two different airlines. 

There should be enough time. Though I'm just concerned cause I'm not sure what procedures apply to my situation :)

Answer (score 3):

I just got an answer from the EasyJet consultant that I will need to go through the security control again.

As long as I abide by 2 hours before the flight I should have no issues with getting on the plane on time.